# Trying to add serial port devices to Centos 7-9 2009

Tags: centos, serial-port

I am trying to figure out a problem in which I am adding 3 more serial ports to the Centos distribution, so that it can talk to all of the serial ports on my embedded PC.  Hopefully, someone can help me get these serial ports working.

BTW, Ubuntu 20.04 by default has enough serial ports (Ubuntu is filled out to 32 ports by default)

On Centos 7-9 2009 I have run:

```
sudo mknod -m 660 /dev/ttyS4 c 4 68
sudo mknod -m 660 /dev/ttyS5 c 4 69
sudo mknod -m 660 /dev/ttyS6 c 4 70
sudo chgrp dialout /dev/ttyS4
sudo chgrp dialout /dev/ttyS5
sudo chgrp dialout /dev/ttyS6
```

And looking at the serial devices:

```
[centos@localhost ~]$ ls /dev/ttyS* -al
crw-rw----. 1 root dialout 4, 64 Aug 22 08:17 /dev/ttyS0
crw-rw----. 1 root dialout 4, 65 Aug 22 08:58 /dev/ttyS1
crw-rw----. 1 root dialout 4, 66 Aug 22 08:58 /dev/ttyS2
crw-rw----. 1 root dialout 4, 67 Aug 22 08:17 /dev/ttyS3
crw-rw----. 1 root dialout 4, 68 Aug 22 08:28 /dev/ttyS4
crw-rw----. 1 root dialout 4, 69 Aug 22 08:28 /dev/ttyS5
crw-rw----. 1 root dialout 4, 70 Aug 22 08:28 /dev/ttyS6
```

If I attempt to use /dev/ttyS4, I get:

```
[centos@localhost ~]$ sudo minicom -D /dev/ttyS4
minicom: cannot open /dev/ttyS4: No such device or address
```

Or if I list out the settings for both /dev/ttyS3 and /dev/ttyS4:

```
[centos@localhost ~]$ sudo setserial /dev/ttyS3
/dev/ttyS3, UART: unknown, Port: 0x02e8, IRQ: 3
#/dev/ttyS0-3 all work.
[centos@localhost ~]$ sudo setserial /dev/ttyS4
/dev/ttyS4: No such device or address
#/dev/ttyS4-6 do not work
```

Also, after a reboot, Centos blew away the new serial ports /dev/ttyS4-6.
One thing I tried is to rebuild the kernel with the option “Number of 8250/16550 serial ports to register at runtime” set to 8, instead of 4.  But I get the exact same problem with only 4 serial ports enumerated in /dev.

Comment: SERIAL_8250_NR_UARTS is 32 and SERIAL_8250_RUNTIME_UARTS is 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I was running the wrong kernel after I built it. When booting the kernel, I see all 8 /dev/ttyS* devices.  It seems that SERIAL_8250_RUNTIME_UARTS = 8 did the trick.

It does only boot in emergency mode, but I think that is because I got warnings during the build about locales not being set during the modules install step, which is not described on the Centos wiki...I will ask another question regarding this.